# ElementName Binding in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, contextmenu

Suppose I have a `Button` named "*myButton*", and inside its `ContextMenu` (named "*myContextMenu*"), I have a `MenuItem` named *"myMenuItem"*.

```xml
<Button Name="myButton">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="myContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I know that the `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem` are not inside the same visual tree or namescope as its `PlacementTarget` `myButton`, so by using `ElementName`, the binding will fail. By using `NameScope.SetNameScope()`, I can make the `ContextMenu` inside the same namescope and then make the binding successful.

```xml
<!-- this will succeed only if setting the namescope in code-behind -->
<MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" />
```

However, without setting the namescope in code-behind, the `Button` can access both the `ContextMenu` and `MenuItem`.

```xml
<!-- this will succeed no matter the namescope is set in code-behind -->
<Button Name="myButton" Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myContextMenu}">
```

Furthermore, I also noticed that the `MenuItem` cannot even access itself or its parent `ContextMenu` by using `ElementName`. But by using `RelativeSource Self`, the binding will succeed.

```xml
<!-- both will fail unless setting namescope in code behind -->
<MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myContextMenu}" />
<MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myMenuItem}" />
<!-- succeed even without setting namescope -->
<MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Command="..." CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

So my questions are:

1. Why Button can access *"myContextMenu"* by `ElementName=myContextMenu` even without setting the namescope of the `ContextMenu`?
2. Why `MenuItem` cannot access itself by `ElementName=myMenuItem` unless setting the namescope?
3. Why `RelativeSource Self` works regardless of the namescope or visual tree?

Comment: Try to add to your Window.Resources local reference to class where the command is located. Then just add staticresource when you are binding, set value to key of local reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1. Why Button can access myContextMenu by ElementName=myContextMenu even without setting the namescope of the MenuContext?**

A [`ContextMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contextmenu?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) element defines what the context menu looks like and how it behaves.

> The properties of the `ContextMenu` class are used to define the position and behavior of the `ContextMenu`. [...]
>
> If you assign a `ContextMenu` to the `FrameworkElement.ContextMenu` or `FrameworkContentElement.ContextMenu` property, the `ContextMenuService` class handles context menu operations in response to user interaction. [...]
>
> *A `ContextMenu` is automatically placed inside a `Popup` control.*

The `ContextMenu` is assigned to the `ContextMenu` property of `Button` and it still exists there throughout the runtime with all the menu items that you created. It lives within the *same namescope* as the `Button`, because [namescopes are created on load when XAML is parsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#namescopes-in-loaded-xaml-applications) and at this point it is part of the `Button`.

> In WPF, XAML namescopes are created on the root element for a XAML page when the page is loaded. Each name specified within the XAML page starting at the page root is added to a pertinent XAML namescope.

Consequently, a `Binding` with `ElementName` resolves successfully as it operates in a single namescope.

> **2. Why MenuItem cannot access itself by ElementName=myMenuItem unless setting the namescope?**

As you can see, the `ContextMenu` is within the same namescope as `Button`. When opening it, the `ContextMenu` is still assinged to the `ContextMenu` property of `Button`, but a new `Popup` that hosts it is assigned as its parent. This also means that it resides in a different visual tree. Nevertheless, it is the *same* instance that the `Button` refers to. This is very important, since [namescopes are not automatically reassigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#adding-objects-to-runtime-object-trees) after the initial assignment.

> The moment that XAML is parsed represents the moment in time that a WPF XAML namescope is created and defined. If you add an object to an object tree at a point in time after the XAML that produced that tree was parsed, a `Name` or `x:Name` value on the new object does not automatically update the information in a XAML namescope.

In summary, the `ContextMenu` is only parented to a `Popup`, but it is still in the same namescope as the `Button`. This can only be changed manually, by adding it to the target namespace in code.

> To add a name for an object into a WPF XAML namescope after XAML is loaded, you must call the appropriate implementation of RegisterName on the object that defines the XAML namescope, which is typically the XAML page root. If the name is not registered, the added object cannot be referenced by name through methods such as FindName, and you cannot use that name for animation targeting.

> **3. Why RelativeSource Self works regardless of the namescope or visual tree?**

A [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) does not use names to resolve elements, therefore it is independent of the actual namescope, but it depends on the visual tree.

> Implements a markup extension that describes the location of the binding source *relative to the position* of the binding target.

In the concrete case of the `ContextMenu`, obviously the `RelativeSource` binding on `MenuItem` can resolve itself, as well as the `ContextMenu`, since they are both part of the same visual tree. However, it cannot resolve `Button`, as the root of the `ContextMenu` at runtime is the `Popup` that was assigned as its parent.

Comment: Thanks! But why the `MenuItem` failed referencing itself by using `ElementName=myMenuItem`? In addition, you mentioned the `ContextMenu` and `Button` are in the same namescope, but I just find out `<ContextMenu Tag="{Binding ElementName=myButton}">` Still fails.

Comment: @Obsidian As I stated in the answer for 2., the namescope is assigned when the XAML is loaded and parsed. Suppose that you have a main window that contains the button with the context menu. All this is within the same XAML file. On load, this XAML code will be parsed and the window gets a namescope. Since it contains the button and its context menu, those will be added to this namescope, too. Now, when you right click the button, a `Popup` is created, which has its own dedicated window. The same context menu instance is parented to the `Popup`, **but** its namescope is not changed.

Comment: @Obsidian This means now that the popup was parsed and created, the bindings try to find the name `myMenuItem` and `myButton` (your `Tag` example) in the *current namescope for the `Popup`* but both the `MenuItem`s and the `Button`  were created in a *different* namescope, the one for the main window, so the bindings that are resolved at runtime in the `Popup` namescope cannot find the corresponding names. Maybe the misunderstanding here is *when* the bindings are resolved and that is not at parse time of the XAML but when the popup is already set up, which is a different context.

Comment: @Obsidian Now, think again, binding *from* the button to the context menu works just fine, because the binding is resolved in the main window, which is ok, since all elements were created in and share this namescope. Again, once the `Popup` is opened, the whole `ContextMenu` was parented there, but its namescope did not change, so binding back to the button will fail, be it from the `Tag` property, the `MenuItem`s or anything else in there. At that point in time the binding resolves in the namescope of the `Popup`. where these names do not exist.